# Encrypting WebConfig

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application, which I publish to three web servers using the 'publish' option.

I want to encrypt the connectionstrings section of the web config file.  The command below will do it:

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" c:\inetpub\application
```

However, I have to RDP (Remote Desktop) to each server and run the command on each server as you cannot run it like this (from a client PC):

\servername\c$\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" \servername\c$\inetpub\application

Is there a better way of doing this: perhaps:

> 1) Execute a command line on the server after publishing 2) Use a
>   build option in Visual Studio that allows you to execute a batch file
>   after publishing is complete

Comment: May I ask why you don't trust your web server.  Also, typically when you generate the the deployment package it should remove the connection string.  I've configured my IIS servers to handle this and add their connection strings in from the IIS console.  This would probably be better than passing a connection string in the web.config file as it allows for easier per machine configurations/load balancing.

Comment: The web app is deployed to a few client PCs in a Local Area Network.  If I don't encrypt the connection strings section; anyone will be able to see the database password who is logged on.

Comment: Fair enough...  Would it be possible for you to use Integrated Security?  If the servers are set up properly this will entirely mitigate your issue but setting up AD authentication for SQL seems to be a very bureaucratic process.

Comment: Think I'm with Sparksis on this one. Seems to me like it'd be easier to avoid the issue entirely by using Integrated Security

Answer (score 5):

Encrypt the connectionStrings section of your web.config on your server and then add this encrypted section to your web.[CONFIGURATION_FOR_SERVER].config transformation file.  The key being the first line which says to replace the connectionStrings portion of your original web.config with this new encrypted value. You'll need a new transformation file for each server that you are publishing to.  Visual Studio will raise a warning (not error) i.e.

```
Warning 15  The element 'connectionStrings' has invalid child element 'EncryptedData' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#'. List of possible elements expected: 'add, remove, clear'.   C:\DevTFS\YourProject\Web.Stage.config  14  6   YourProject
```

about the format of this transformation file - I haven't found the correct syntax to get around this so I'm open to suggestions, but it still works so I'm happy. Full blog entry on this: http://randomdotnetnuggets.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/publishing-encrypted-connection-strings.html

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" xdt:Transform="Replace">
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
  <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>          
         <CipherValue>t8p7aOZTjMo...zE6FAAI=</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedKey>
  </KeyInfo>
  <CipherData>
    <CipherValue>Vy1TZWY8....ic+Qg6T7U</CipherValue>
  </CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

Answer (score 1):

If Integrated Security is not an option, I suggest you [MS Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).

When you build a [deployment package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323.aspx) with Visual Studio 2012, you'll get a zip file and command line script files. You can modify that script file to encrypt your web.config or roll your own batch script or powershell script.

Comment: Support for Encrypting web.config sections post deployment has been added in version 3.5 of Web Deploy. https://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2013/07/09/webdeploy-3-5-rtw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but this answer may help someone.

In a load balanced or web farm scenario, you can encrypt the file once and copy the web.config to other machines. However, for this to work, you must use the same Machine Key for each website.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx

Hope this helps anyone searching for this.